# openshift set environment variable from a file

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift

I have a mount volume has a file `urls.txt` with database source url, like

```
databasesource: mysql://xxxx
```

and in my springboot application which will be running as a container in a openshift pod, and in the application I need to change the SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL as mentioned in the file above, here is what I want to achieve in my template file

```
 env:
   - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
     valueFrom:
       mount:
         name: my-volume
         key: databasesource
   volumeMounts:
     - name: my-volume
       mountPath: /someDir
```

I know we can valueFrom configMap or secret, but I want to achieve via a volumeMount

Answer (score 0):

if you can use below format in

urls.txt

```
databasesource=mysql://xxxx
```

as part of your container start you run

```
source /somedir/urls.txt
```

which will load the key & values in env. which can be further used.

Comment: I've change it to databasesource=mysql://xxxx format, and run the source command in lifecycle lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /bin/bash
                  - '-c'
                  - source /somedir/urls.txt but still not work

Comment: postStart hook is an async process. might not guarantee it’s executed before entry point.  You can have script which can execute the source cmd. Invoke as part entry point.

Comment: ok, I found a solution in springboot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by a Springboot2.0 feature: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.importing-extensionless